# c2955 error on my Double Link List project

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

Okay, I'm making a project that implements a Double Linked List using classes, templates and structures.
I constantly get the error:

```
doublelinklist.h(21) : error C2955: 'Node' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

when declaring the head and tail of a node in the LinkedList class.

DoubleLinkList.h:

```
#ifndef DOUBLELINKLIST_H
#define DOUBLELINKLIST_H
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL 0
#endif
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string>

template <class T>
struct Node 
{
 T val;
 Node * next;
 Node * prev; //both of these are self-referential data types/structures
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
 static Node * head; //C2955
 static Node * tail; //C2955
public:
 bool push(T);
 //bool pop();
 //T at(); //C2146
 //bool clear();

 LinkedList()
 {
  /*static Node * */head = NULL;
  /*static Node * */tail = NULL;
 }
 ~LinkedList()
 {}
};

#endif
```

DoubleLinkList.cpp

```
#include "DoubleLinkList.h"

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::push(T pushMe)
{
 Node * newN = new Node;

 newN->next = NULL;
 newN->prev = NULL;

 if(this->head == NULL)
 {
  head = newN;
  head->val = pushMe;
  tail = newN;
  printf("the value in the head is %d\n", head->val);
  return true;
 }

 newN->prev = tail;
 tail->next = newN;
 newN->pushMe;
 tail = newN;

 printf("The value in the head is %d\n", head->val);
 return true;
}

//bool LinkedList::pop(int remove_where)
//{
// Node * toRemove = at(remove_where);
//
// if(toRemove == head)
// {
//  toRemove->next->prev = NULL;
//  head = toRemove->next;
// }
//
// else if(toRemove = tail)
// {
//  toRemove->prev->next = NULL;
//  tail = toRemove->prev;
// }
// 
// else
// {
//  toRemove->prev->next = toRemove->next;
//  toRemove->next->prev = toRemove->prev;
// }
//
// delete toRemove;
//
// return true;
//
//}
//
//T LinkedList::at()
//{
// 
// 
//}
//
//LinkedList::clear()
//{
// 
//
//}
```

main.cpp

/*

```
1) Implement a Double-Linked List using templates and classes in C++.
   You may use the STL type "List" as a reference. 
   A) Don't forget to implement a NODE class...
   B) Don't forget to implement a class that is the actual list...
        i) You need to have AT LEAST:

            Push
            Pop
            At
            Clear 

2) Write a program that tests the functionality of your list class with the data types "int" and "std::string".
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "DoubleLinkList.h"

//template <class T>
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    LinkedList<int> derp;
    derp.push(x);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual error. The error code is not enough by itself.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: Paste the actual error text, fix the main.cpp paste, don't define your own NULL, include one of the appropriate headers instead. Or better, reduce the problem into self contained testcase that won't require more than one short file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error C2955 ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9h89b20(VS.80).aspx)) relates to the absence of a type argument list to types that require one. In your code you reference the type `Node` which is actually a template and requires a type argument list. The fixes are below:

First of all, in `DoubleLinkedList.h` in the declaration of `LinkedList` (in the `private:` section at the top):

```
static Node * head;
static Node * tail;
```

should be (they should also not be declared `static` since I'm pretty certain each individual linked list needs its own head and tail):

```
Node<T> * head;
Node<T> * tail;
```

since `Node` is actually the template class `Node<T>` and requires the type parameter itself.

Similarly in `DoubleLinkedList.cpp` in the `push` method:

```
Node * newN = new Node;
```

should be:

```
Node<T> * newN = new Node<T>;
```

for the same reason.

Furthermore, template definitions should be defined in header files and the header files included using `#include`, e.g. `#include "DoubleLinkedList.h"`, (and not compiled as you would `.cpp` files) since template expansion to produce concrete versions of the classes is performed by the preprocessor. Finally, there is also a problem with `newN->pushMe;` in your definition of `LinkedList<T>::push`: no such method exists. Fix these issues and there's a chance it might compile! Beyond that I don't vouch for the correctness of the code.

Comment: ++ I suspected something like this after looking up what the error code meant.

Comment: It worked. Now I get the errors: LNK2019 and two LNK2001s. Pasting the full details in here would make everything looked jumbled up.

Comment: Can you summarize the error messages? What are the unresolved symbol names?

Comment: For the 2019, it's "public: bool __thiscall LinkedList<int>::push(int)";         For the other two, it's "private: static struct Node<int> * LinkedList<int>::tail" and "private: static struct Node<int> * LinkedList<int>::head"

Comment: It's certainly in my project. Do I actually have to #include DoubleLinkedList.cpp somewhere?

Comment: Templates should not be split into separate `.cpp` and `.h` files. So merge the content of `DoubleLinkedList.cpp` into the `.h` file and remove the `.cpp` file altogether. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Also see my comment about the `head` and `tail` members: they should be instance variables not `static`.

Comment: Are you saying it's just not possible to use Templates across multiple files? Or is it possible, but just really difficult?

Comment: No, it's possible but they need to be included using `#include` like you would header files and *not* compiled like `.cpp` files normally are. I added this clarification to my answer.

Comment: putting something like "#include template <class T>" in the header of DoubleLinkList.cpp causes another error.

Comment: You need to insert `#include "DoubleLinkedList.cpp"` into your `main.cpp` source file. But I would highly recommend renaming `DoubleLinkedList.cpp` to something with a `.h` file name extension to indicate that it is a header file and not a source file to be compiled.

Comment: Thanks! That actually seemed to get the job done. I already had the .h version in there anyway.